# SELECT LEFT JOIN con releacion One-To-Many 0

Tags: sql, join

Recientemente me toco realizar unas consultas para una API Rest, y tenían una tabla de usuarios e invitaciones, donde la relación es un usuario a cero o muchas invitaciones (One-To-Many)  se me dio la tarea de regresar un JSON que regresara los datos del usuario y si ya había tenido invitación ( true o false ),

Eso se podría 2 de las siguientes opciones:

**1.-**

```
SELECT U.nombre, U.email (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Notificaciones AS N WHERE N.UserId = U.Id) AS Notifications FROM Users AS U;

   Y dentro del loop del backend:

tieneNotificaciones = false;
   if rs.getField('Notifications') > 0 {
     tieneNotificaciones = true;
   }
```

**2-** `SELECT U.Id, U.nombre, U.email FROM Users AS U;`

Y dentro del loop del backend hacer otra consulta por cada registro:

```
int IdUser = rs.getField('id')
   string query = 'SELECT COUN(*) FROM Notificaciones AS N WHERE N.UserId = U.Id' 
   int totalNotificaciones = stm.exec( query )
   tieneNotificaciones = false;
   if totalNotificaciones > 0 {
     tieneNotificaciones = true;
   }
```

Las 2 soluciones de arriba funcionarían pero a mi punto de vista seria ejecutar 1 consulta por cada registro, lo cual lo va a hacer algo lento el web servicie

Se me ocurrió hacer un LEFT JOIN entre estas tablas, pero veo que me multiplica los registros de usuario por los registros que tengo en notificaciones, ahora mi duda seria: ¿Cómo puedo hacer un LEFT JOIN, donde solo me traiga el id de Notificaciones del primero registro que encuentre?

es decir algo como esto:

```
SELECT U.nombre, U.email, N.id FROM Users AS U LEFT JOIN Notificaciones AS N ON U.Id = N.userId
```

**Pero como lo menciones que el N.id sea sólo el ultimo registro que se inserto  nulo o cero si no existe registro en Notificaciones**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no he acabado de entender los requerimientos, pero te daré las opciones que tienes

Con un `LEFT JOIN` obtenemos una lista con todos los usuarios, utilizando la función de agregación `MAX()` obtenemos la última notificación o bien `MIN()` para obtener la primera notificación de cada usuario. Si el usuario no tiene notificación aparecerá como `NULL`.

```
SELECT U.nombre, U.email, MIN(N.id) as notificacionId
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Notificaciones AS N ON U.Id = N.userId
GROUP BY U.nombre, U.email
```

Ejemplo

```
nombre     email      notificacionId
Pepe       p@p.com      5
Juan       j@p.com      null
```

Si solo quieres la lista de usuarios que tengan alguna notificación puedes utilizar el `INNER JOIN` o bien el `LEFT JOIN` añadiendo la condición `WHERE N.id is not null`

Answer (score 0):

La manera más intuitiva y por tanto el 90% de las veces la más sensata ya te la respondió [Roger Tomé](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/144817/roger-torn%C3%A9).  Como enunciado general para tu caso

**Dada una tabla U, y una tabla T que referencia a la primera, se puede usar GROUP BY agrupando por U.*, y presentar agregados para cualquier campo de T.**

en caso de no existir registros en la tabla dependiente, los agregados mediante funciones  como `min`, `max`, `avg`... son nulos. El resultado de `count`, por su parte es cero.

Adicionalmente,

> Se me ocurrió hacer un LEFT JOIN entre estas tablas, pero veo que me
> multiplica los registros de usuario por los registros que tengo en
> notificaciones,

El resultado se colapsa hasta presentar una fila por cada registro único de entre las columnas no agrupadas. (En este caso, un registro por cada tupla *[id,nombre]*). O sea no tendrás ese problema siempre y cuando esté bien planteado cuales son columnas agregadas y cuales no.

Como complemento, aunque es rebuscado para este caso de uso, podrías tener un escenario en donde las notificaciones no se insertan necesariamente en orden cronológico, de manera que no siempre se cumpla que `MIN(N.id)` es la primera notificación.

Para saber el `id` de la notificación más antigua entre las dirigidas al usuario,  antes de MySQL 8 la solución era básicamente <strike>darse de cabezasos con la pared</strike> hacer una o más subqueries. Ahora en cambio se puede usar [WINDOW FUNCTIONS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

```
SELECT U.nombre, U.email, 
  FIRST_VALUE(N.id) OVER  (PARTITION BY U.id ORDER BY sentDate ASC) as firstNotificationId 
FROM Users AS U 
LEFT JOIN Notificaciones AS N ON U.Id = N.userId ;
```

En este ejemplo que hice en [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HeJyro7TuWfrP3VQaQmEw/3) podrán ver los datos que hay detrás, pero básicamente, si desplegamos el id del registro más antiguo junto al mínimo id,

```
SELECT U.nombre,
       U.email,
       FIRST_VALUE(N.id) OVER w as firstNotificationId,
       MIN(N.id) OVER w         as minNotificationId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER w      as rowNum
FROM Users AS U
         LEFT JOIN Notificaciones AS N ON U.Id = N.userId
    WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY U.id ORDER BY sentDate ASC);
```

| nombre | email | firstNotificationId | minNotificationId | rowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pedro | pedro@mail.com | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| Pedro | pedro@mail.com | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| Pedro | pedro@mail.com | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| Juan | juan@mail.com | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| Juan | juan@mail.com | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| Juan | juan@mail.com | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| Diego | diego@mail.com |  |  | 1 |

<kbd>[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HeJyro7TuWfrP3VQaQmEw/3)</kbd>

Se ve que no necesariamente son  iguales (por tanto se justifica este método en el caso de borde) y se ve también que, al no utilizar GROUP BY, no se colapsan las tuplas repetidas, lo cual es muy impráctico cuando quieres obtener la primera, pero es muy bueno cuando en realidad querías, por ejemplo, las dos primeras.

La lista con los usuarios y *sus dos notificaciones más antiguas* sería mediante la subquery

```
SELECT nombre,email,firstNotificationId FROM (
  SELECT U.nombre,
       U.email,
       FIRST_VALUE(N.id) OVER w as firstNotificationId,
       MIN(N.id) OVER w         as minNotificationId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER w      as rowNum
  FROM Users AS U
         LEFT JOIN Notificaciones AS N ON U.Id = N.userId
    WINDOW w as (PARTITION BY U.id ORDER BY sentDate ASC)
) mainQuery
WHERE rowNum<=2
```

Con el mismo método podríamos listar el texto de la notificación más antigua, la fecha de la notificación más extensa, etc etc